# Unable to build gradle; Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> *Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @3bcb9348*

I am receiving this error on building a project in Android-Studio, I have tried almost all the methods suggested on stack-overflow and youtube, I have tried completely removing all android studio files and reinstalling them but still am unable to sort it.

These are my build.gradle files

**build.gradle: (Module: EmployerModule.app)**

```
*plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.employermodule"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}*
```

**Build.gradle(EmployerModule)**

```
*// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}*
```

Comment: I started to see this when updating my jdk from java 15 to java 16. Don't know yet how to fix it (except downgrading the jdk).  I'll post here if I find out more!

Comment: Found a related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187445005